# How to develop Intellij idea plugin with Messages dialog

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Question 1: I use "Messages.showDialog" to show a dialog, but that dialog doesn't display the icon i supplied, it uses a java icon. when i use "Messages.showChooseDialog" to show a dialog, that icon display correctly. Why "Messages.showDialog" doesn't use my icon?

Question 2:I find that "Messages.showChooseDialog" was deprecated, what's alternatives?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development is a better place for such questions.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you.